# Automate TortoiseSVN commit using cruise control

Tags: tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

I am new to tortoise svn, can any one tell how to automate tortoisesvn's commit process using CruiseControl.NET . My attempt to do that results in an exception being thrown.

My main concern is to auto close the window that pops up when we execute the command

```
"tortoiseproc /command: commit /path:"**********PATH********* /logmsg:
"log msg" /closeonend:1"
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use GUI tool for batch scripts. Subversion have [packages for Windows](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) that will give you powerful `svn` command. And you'll be able to do `svn commit -m "log msg"` without any windows popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an msbuild script you can use from ccnet that will commit, but leave a dialog up if there are errors.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TortoisePath>C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe</TortoisePath>  
    <TortoiseCommit>&quot;$(TortoisePath)&quot; /command:commit /path:</TortoiseCommit>
    <DbProjLocalPath>$(LocalBranchPath)\Database\DBProject</DbProjLocalPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="SvnCommitDbProj">
<Error Condition="!Exists($(DbProjLocalPath))" Text="Directory missing:$(DbProjLocalPath)" />
<Exec Command="$(TortoiseCommit)&quot;$(DbProjLocalPath)&quot;" IgnoreExitCode="true">

    </Exec>
</Target>
```

I don't see a way in tortoise to enforce that the dialog will always close

`/closeonend:1 auto close if no errors` from [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

Because of this you may want to use svn as vava suggests.